# import google-sample-code from github to java app

Tags: java, maven, google-bigquery

I would like to use the following function from [google java-docs-samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigquery/samples/BigQueryUtils.java) in my code like this:

```
BigQueryUtils.getPages(...)
```

I added in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and in my code:

```
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.samples;

public class MyClass {

  public static void method() {
    BigQueryUtils.getPages(...);
  }
```

i get this message:

```
 The import com.google.cloud.bigquery.samples cannot be resolved
```

how can I  import above libraries in my project?

**EDIT**
I also tried adding this on the pom, didnt help

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>doc-samples</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I get this message in the pom:

```
Missing artifact com.google.cloud:doc-samples:jar:1.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The samples/examples are not part of the Maven central repo. As per the [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/bigquery), you would need to build the project yourself, and then [include the local jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project) that is built if you want to use those classes/methods:

1. Clone/download the [repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples)
2. `cd` to bigquery
3. `mvn clean package -DskipTests`
4. Include the jar in your project

Bear in mind though, that these are just samples/examples. I wouldn't be depending on them for building solutions. They exist purely to guide and get people started with the APIs.